# Using Play Templates Elsewhere

Tags: java, playframework

Is it possible to use the templating engine from the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) in other contexts?  Ideally I'd like an api of the form:

```
String result = render("template-file.html",var1,var2);
```

In some frameworks the templating engine is entirely usable outside of the framework, or even standalone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the template engine within Play is Groovy, so first off you could take a look if by simply using Groovy is enough for what you want to achieve.

The best place to look is the [Groovy Templating](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates) system. I would recommend this rather than trying to unpick, or bundling the Play code.

Comment: well, in fact play! adds a lot of stuff on his own, like template inheritance, tags, reverse routing, etc...

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you can use templating engine outside Play context but you can generate the html page like this :

```
Map args = new HashMap();
args.put("var1",var1);
...
String html = TemplateLoader.load("contact.html",args).render();
```

Answer (score 7):

I asked the very same question on Play's mailing list. Answer :

```
String result = TemplateLoader.load("virtual/path/to/file").render(mapOfParameters);
```

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.3/play%2Ftemplates%2FTemplateLoader.html